# How can I query from one report Tab to another tab the number of calls handled by employees ignoring calls <2min?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have a call report with two different tabs

## TAB 1) "RAWDATA" - Range:A:AB -

a log of two employees´ handled outbound and inbound calls and more columns that are not relevant now.

- IMPORTANT COLUMNS:

"D" - SKILL NAME.
Type of call). for us INBOUND would be "RVL_US_Scheduling_PC" and OUTBOUND would be either "RVL_US_Scheduling_OB_PC" or "RVL_US_SchedulingExpress_OB_PC

"I" - CONTACT AGENT NAME
The corresponding column with the employees name in our system

"W" - HANDLE TIME
Te report will inform how long each call lasted which leaves us with the need to only extract only calls greater than 2 MIN

### ADDITONAL COLUMN

For OUTBOUND column "V" can also be considered.

## TAB 2) "CALLS BY AGENT" - Range: A:E -

This is the tab where I would like to "query" to:

- NUMBER OF CALLS HANDLED BY AGENT AND BY TYPE (INBOUND AND OUTBOUND) separately on columns: Kevin: C3 and C4, and Sandra: D3 and D4.

So far I've partially come up with one formula for "inbound":

=QUERY(RAWDATA!A2:W, "select COUNT(D) where I='Aldana, Kevin, Mejia' AND D='RVL_US_Scheduling_PC'")

Unfortunately, when I try to use another "AND" function as follows:

AND W>2:00:00

to limit the query to retrieve only calls longer than 2 min, it´s marking Value Error!

### PLEASE HELP ME, TEAM!

I have tried everything even transforming the "duration" (handle time) column to all "formats", and changing it to even proper numbers and change the formula to numeric value and it won't work!

Can anybody assist with the inbound and outbound call count formula for this case scenario? Here´s the file (permissions are open)

Comment: file is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vPb9fDt_zJmevT2cQywtQFYOS4ibW744zWRh1Nfql8g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

> Use [**Filter**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) instead and control the conditions with a [dropdown list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) highlighted in yellow. and [`counta`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en) the output.

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(RAWDATA!$D$2:$D,RAWDATA!$D$2:$D=B3,RAWDATA!$X$2:$X>$F$3,RAWDATA!I2:I=C$1))
```

[image]